# Data tables warning:json data from server could not be parsed

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I have a code the main intention of code is to implement jquery datatable and render json data. I am successfully getting data from controller in json format.when I run the code it is showing an alert json data from server could not be parsed. Please help. I am attaching code also.

### Controller:-

```
 public JsonResult This_is_final(int FirstNameCount, int LastNameCount, int TotalSalary, int GenderCount)
        {
            List<Counting> l = new List<Counting>();
            l.Add(new Counting() { FirstNamecount = FirstNameCount, LastNamecount = LastNameCount, Salary = TotalSalary, Gendercount = GenderCount });

            var todoListsResults = l.Select(
                 a => new
                 {

                     a.FirstNamecount,
                     a.LastNamecount,
                     a.Salary,
                     a.Gendercount

                 });

            var jsonData = new
            {

                aadata= todoListsResults
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

### Js code:-

```
function callme(fncount, lncount, i, gndr) {
    var dataset = [fncount, lncount, i, gndr];
    //var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    $.post('/TodoList/This_is_final', { 'FirstNameCount': fncount, 'LastNameCount': lncount, 'TotalSalary': i, 'GenderCount': gndr }, function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "aaData": data,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
               "bRetrieve": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "aaData": "FirstNamecount" },
                { "aaData": "LastNamecount" },
                { "aaData": "TotalSalary" },
                { "aaData": "GenderCount" }
            ]

        });

    });

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Correct DataTables initialization code that would work with your data format is shown below:

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
    "aaData": data,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "sAjaxDataProp": "aadata",
    "aoColumns": [
         { "mData": "FirstNamecount" },
         { "mData": "LastNamecount" },
         { "mData": "Salary" },
         { "mData": "Gendercount" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I tried the solution you suggested but it is showing message no data available in the data table.I found no error if I press f12 in the chrome browser

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to stringify the data when you pass it to `aaData`.

```
"aaData": JSON.stringify(data),
```